# Update table value when inserting to other table

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on Laravel and my question is: How can I update value in one table when inserting data to another? Do I have to write new function in controller or update existing or maybe its done on form level in eloquent (view?)?

For example:

That's my OrderController.php function handling inserting:

```
public function insert(Request $request){

        $order = new order;

        $order->material_id = $request->material_id;
        $order->invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;
        $order->count_order = $request->count_order;

        $order->save();
        return redirect('/order');
    }
```

order.blade.php form that inserts data looks like:

```
<form method="POST" action="/order">

    <div class="form-group">

        <input list="invoices" name="invoice_id" autocomplete="off">
        <datalist id="invoices">
        @foreach($invoices as $invoice)
        <option value="{{$invoice->id}}">{{$invoice->number}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </datalist>

        <input list="materials" name="material_id" autocomplete="off">
        <datalist id="materials">
        @foreach($materials as $material)
        <option value="{{$material->id}}">{{$material->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </datalist>

        <input type="count" name="count_order" placeholder="Ilość zamówiona" autocomplete="off">

    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj zamówienie</button>
    </div>
{{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Orders table has:

```
| id | count_order | material_id | invoice_id |
```

Materials table has:

```
| id | name | count_all | count_current | price_unit |
```

Now I want to update column (add value) **count_all** in **Materials** when I post value in a form when inserting to **count_order** column in **Orders** table.

Comment: You will have to do a separate query to update this value. That's why storing computable data is usually avoided. Whenever you can get a value, such as the count of other elements, it is recommended to do so via the query (e.g. by doing a join). That saves you from inconsistencies across your database and potential sources of bugs.

Comment: Ok. But I wonder... if I have inserted to Orders: 10 Pens how can I capture this amount and pass it to that query so it will update the count_all for that exact value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use if

```
$query = $order->save();

if($query){
  //do update data
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I achived it by using "if($query){
            DB::table('materials')
                ->where('id', $request->material_id)
                ->increment('count_all', $request->count_order);
        }"
Now I have to figure out how to apply this to edit but you gave me a good understanding where to start. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `save()` function in Order model, there you would have the value you need and you can perform an update in Materials